# validate in python with lxml's iterparse against multiple DTDs conditionally

Tags: python, lxml, dtd, iterparse

I am parsing and validating fairly large XMLs (>100MB) against multiple DTDs, conditionally, based on the docinfo:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
xmlfile = etree.parse(file,parser)
if "aaa.dtd" in xmlfile.docinfo.doctype.lower():
    dtdfile= "dtds/aaa.dtd"
elif "bbb.dtd" in xmlfile.docinfo.doctype.lower():
    dtdfile= "dtds/bbb.dtd"
elif "ccc.dtd" in xmlfile.docinfo.doctype.lower():
    dtdfile= "dtds/ccc.dtd"
dtd = etree.DTD(dtdfile)
if dtd.validate(xmlfile)==True:
    do sth
```

My problem is memory consumption, so I thought I should use iterparse instead but I can't find a way to do the same kind of validation.

Thanks in advance.